# Re use autogenerated ID in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a procedure where customers trigger a calculation that fills a table with calculated data for further use in their session. But, we have to do this every time they login by deleting all their records and then filling the table again by using `insert into .. select`.

I know it's better to update rows, but there are way to many things that can change / become obsolete after a while, so we decided to delete and reinsert.

This works fine, but I'm worried about the fact that somewhere in time we will hit the limit of our autogenerated RowId integer.

Is there a nice way to reuse the old RowId's that have been deleted? Or is there another approach to make sure we never get into trouble?

Thanks for thinking with me!

Comment: Sorry, i totally forgot to mention, Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2. I updated the title with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you're unlikely to run out of ID values any time soon. I'd ask another question though. Do you really need this ID? If the calculations are specific to a user and session then it seems to me that you already have a way to identify rows. Just put the user id and session id in the table, maybe with a date/time column as well if needed and you don't need an autogenerated ID at all.

Comment: Everyone, Thanks for all advice. I did some counting, and i guessed, that in theory, because of the many many records we use, we could hit that limit somewhere over time. As i didn't like that idea, we refactored some parts or our logic, and with that we we able to remove the ID completely.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the identity field, in every database there is a way to reset the number to whatever you want. Just google your db and reset identity to get the correct syntax.

Best way to do that is to write a little script that you can run sometimes to change all the existing IDs starting with 1 and then set identity to the max + 1.

For example: if your current ids are 12331, 12332, 12333
the scrip would change these ids to 1,2,3 and reset the identity field to 4.
So next entered id would be 4.

Answer (score 0):

Your somewhere-in-time is likely hundreds of years in the future. Unless you're writing software to last *that* long you shouldn't have to worry.

```
count_of_users * count_of_sessions * count_of_days < (much less than) MAX(int)
```

For example:

```
1000 * 100 * 1000 (~3 years) = 100 million = an order of magnitude less than 1 billion
```

Collect some metrics and make a calculation like this and you will likely find that your upper bound is likely generations off.

Answer (score 0):

The Oracle NUMBER can hold up to 38 decimal digits. If you generated a new ID **every nanosecond**, you'd spend them all after [`3.16887646 * 10^21`](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHKZ_enRS439RS439&aq=f&gcx=c&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=nanosecond#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&rlz=1C1CHKZ_enRS439RS439&source=hp&q=10%5E38%20nanoseconds%20in%20years&pbx=1&oq=10%5E38%20nanoseconds%20in%20years&aq=f&aqi=&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=5378l9587l2l10281l12l11l0l0l0l1l227l1829l0.9.2l11l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=b571422ac7922aeb&biw=1257&bih=1210) years.

Our universe is about `14 * 10^9` years old. Trust me, you won't "spend" IDs any time soon.

(Other databases have similar "limitations".)

Answer (score 0):

You won't run out of generated ID values, but you can use the **replace into** command. You can find a good reference [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html).

Answer (score 0):

With a type `INT`, starting at 1, you get **over 2 billion** possible rows - that should be more than sufficient for the vast majority of cases. With `BIGINT`, you get roughly **922 quadrillion** (922 with 15 zeros - 922'000 billions) - enough for you??

If you use an `INT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert a row every second, you need 66.5 **years** before you hit the 2 billion limit ....

If you use a `BIGINT IDENTITY` starting at 1, and you insert **one thousand rows every second**, you need a mind-boggling **292 million years** before you hit the 922 quadrillion limit ....

Read more about it (with all the options there are) in the [MSDN Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186775.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This should give you a list of your tables, and show you how close you are to filling the identity columns of each (this should work SQL 2005+). Alternative versions (inc. a SQL 2000 version) are available [here](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/sql_server_check_identity_columns.htm).

```
SELECT  QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)) + '.' +  QUOTENAME(t.name) AS TableName, 
    c.name AS ColumnName,
    CASE c.system_type_id
        WHEN 127 THEN 'bigint'
        WHEN 56 THEN 'int'
        WHEN 52 THEN 'smallint'
        WHEN 48 THEN 'tinyint'
    END AS 'DataType',
    IDENT_CURRENT(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)  + '.' + t.name) AS CurrentIdentityValue,
    CASE c.system_type_id
        WHEN 127 THEN (IDENT_CURRENT(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)  + '.' + t.name) * 100.) / 9223372036854775807
        WHEN 56 THEN (IDENT_CURRENT(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)  + '.' + t.name) * 100.) / 2147483647
        WHEN 52 THEN (IDENT_CURRENT(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)  + '.' + t.name) * 100.) / 32767
        WHEN 48 THEN (IDENT_CURRENT(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)  + '.' + t.name) * 100.) / 255
    END AS 'PercentageUsed' 
FROM    sys.columns AS c 
    INNER JOIN
    sys.tables AS t 
    ON t.[object_id] = c.[object_id]
WHERE   c.is_identity = 1
ORDER BY PercentageUsed DESC
```